# Drupel 7 - How do I add an additional page template as a choice to the add content list?

Tags: templates, drupal-7

In Drupal 7 when I go to add content I get a list of templates to choose from:

- Article
- Basic Page
- Panel

Lets say I want to create a custom 'page' template (for what ever reason) and have it show up as a choice in this list. Example:

- Article
- Basic Page
- Panel
- Crazy Page

Like how individual pages can be set to use a specific custom Page Template in Wordpress. How would I do that in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a new content type under structure > content types. There you could add whatever fields you are needing, and also manage the basic display of nodes. A content type is the structural definition, a node is the created content page.

More detailed information here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/create-a-custom-content-type

Comment: But I want to create a completely different page template with different html that may  or may not include a header and footer for example.

Comment: You would still create your custom content type, but then within your theme you could add an additional template. Basically you would copy the theme template you want to use (most likely node.tpl.php) and then create one for your specific content type. eg. node--crazy-page.tpl.php

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7.x

Comment: Thank you @kimberly I appreciate your effort. I am aware of the explained method but it does not answer my actual question. Whether it's good practice or not asside, I would like to know how to add an additional page template as a choice to the add content list. Like how individual pages can be set to use a specific custom Page Template in Wordpress. I want to know if it's possible and if so, how. I hope I didn't offend with this reply...

Comment: In Drupal you create different types of content through content types instead of assigning a template to a page. Content types can have different fields, permissions, displays. So that is the first step you take structure > content types > add new. This would make a new type appear in the Add content list and you would be able to create new pages of that type.

In your theme, you would create a new template for your new content type, and this would allow you to add/edit all the HTML you wanted for that content type. 
https://drupalize.me/videos/content-types-drupal-7?p=1166

Comment: THANK YOU @kimberly